# Collapsing Toolbar Layout - Textview hide behind Actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a problem with my textview. The textview is always hiding behind the Actionbar when the page is scrolled, but I want it to stay at the top of the screen.

There is image example: [Screenshot](https://s8.postimg.org/u8fdj76yd/Screenshot_2017_02_28_18_35_58_com_example_juraj.png)

Here is my code in the `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java` file.

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="280dip"
        app:elevation="0dip"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGreen"
        app:expanded="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="#76BC18"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorLightGreen">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/salmon"
                android:id="@+id/profile_id"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dip"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/food"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/expandedappbar"
                    android:background="@color/colorLightGreen" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="30dip"
                android:paddingTop="35dip"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/cena_pro_studenta"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/collapsedappbar"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:text="37 Kč"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingLeft="7dip"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/collapsedappbar" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/alergeny"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/collapsedappbar"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/listView"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:dividerHeight="0dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="30dip"
                android:background="#ECEFF0"
                android:paddingBottom="15dip"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/smile"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:layout_width="45dip" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/Prumer"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/collapsedappbar"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:text="@string/hodnotenie"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

                    <Button
                        android:text="@string/pridej_foto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="30dip"
                android:paddingTop="30dip"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alert"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_height="25dip"
                        android:layout_width="45dip"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/OpravaText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/collapsedappbar"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/nahlasit_chybu"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>




    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;
        private ListView listView;

        String[] listItems = {"Obiloviny obsahujíci lepek" , "Podzemnice ojelná (arašidy)"};
        Integer[] imgid={
                R.drawable.pic1,
                R.drawable.pic2,
        };


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setTitle(null);

            collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);


            CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this, listItems, imgid);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
            return true;
        }




        /* Metoda pre zobrazenie celého ListView */

        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight
                    + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }



    }
```